# How to check a public RSA key file is well formed?

Tags: openssl, rsa

Inside a shell script I want verify a public RSA file. I want to find a way to check if this file is a genuine public key file, nothing else.

What are the ways I can verify this input file to check this is a genuine public key file, not a regular file?

I will be using this public key file in the future to validate an incoming encrypt gzip file, but that is out of scope for now.

I want to validate the input file to check its genuine RSA public key file is not an ordinary file. Please note that I do not have any other files with me (for example, a private key).

For example, if the file is `‘public.pem’` I just want check inside that it’s a genuine RSA public key file, not just a file with texts or file is not corrupted.
I’m already checking that file is not zero sized and the MD5 hash.

#### Other possible checks I found

Check the file contains the text `‘BEGIN PUBLIC KEY’` and `‘END PUBLIC KEY’`.
I also found the following command using Google Search. Is there a better way to do this using OpenSSL?

```
openssl rsa -noout -text -inform PEM -in pubkey.pem -pubin
```

Comment: use this site to debug https://8gwifi.org/certsverify.jsp

Answer (score 4):

I found a satisfying answer in [an answer to Stack Overflow question *How to check a public RSA key file*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259432/how-to-check-a-public-rsa-key-file/26260514#26260514).